# Zoom on amchart map, depending on group of locations

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts

I have the following [amchart map](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/map-bubbles/)

```
var latlong = data.geo;
   var mapData = data.regions;

 var minBulletSize = 1;
    var maxBulletSize = 50;
    var min = Infinity;
    var max = -Infinity;



// get min and max values
    for (var i = 0; i < mapData.length; i++) {
        var value = mapData[i].value;
        if (value < min) {
            min = value;
        }
        if (value > max) {
            max = value;
        }
    }
AmCharts.theme = AmCharts.themes.light;
window.map = new AmCharts.AmMap();

window.map.areasSettings = {
    unlistedAreasColor: "#000000",
    unlistedAreasAlpha: 0.1,
    autoZoom: true,
    selectedColor: "#CC0000"
};

window.map.smallMap = {
    mapColor: "#3faba4"
};

window.map.mouseWheelZoomEnabled = true;
window.map.zoomOnDoubleClick = true;

window.map.imagesSettings.balloonText = "<span style='font-size:14px;'><b>[[title]]</b>: [[value]]</span>";
window.map.imagesSettings.alpha = 0.8;

var dataProvider = {
    mapVar: AmCharts.maps.worldLow,
    images: [],
    getAreasFromMap: true
}


for (var i = 0; i < mapData.length; i++) {
    var dataItem = mapData[i];
    var value = dataItem.value;
    // calculate size of a bubble
    var size = (value - min) / (max - min) * (maxBulletSize - minBulletSize) + minBulletSize;
    if (size < minBulletSize) {
        size = minBulletSize;
    }
    var id = dataItem.code;


    dataProvider.images.push({
        type: "circle",
        width: size,
        height: size,
        color: dataItem.color,
        longitude: latlong[id].longitude,
        latitude: latlong[id].latitude,
        title: dataItem.name,
        value: value
    });
}

window.map.dataProvider = dataProvider;
window.map.export = {
    enabled: true
}
window.map.projection = "Miller";
window.map.write("chartdiv");
```

and the data im filling the map with is something like this

```
{"data":{

"geo":{
    "liège":{
        "latitude":50.6244465,
        "longitude":5.5285034
    },
    "sarthe":{
        "latitude":47.9925739,
        "longitude":0.2093181
    },
    "mersch":{
        "latitude":49.724161,
        "longitude":6.1242871
    },
    "greater_manchester":{
        "latitude":53.47108559999999,
        "longitude":-2.2943756
    },
    "córdoba":{
        "latitude":37.89183,
        "longitude":-4.819809999999999
    },
    "coimbra":{
        "latitude":40.1585918,
        "longitude":-8.8696372
    },
    "soest":{
        "latitude":52.1590547,
        "longitude":5.3067835
    }
},
"regions":[
    {
        "code":"liège",
        "name":"Liège",
        "value":3,
        "color":"#eea638"
    },
    {
        "code":"sarthe",
        "name":"Sarthe",
        "value":3,
        "color":"#eea638"
    },
    {
        "code":"mersch",
        "name":"Mersch",
        "value":6,
        "color":"#eea638"
    },
    {
        "code":"greater_manchester",
        "name":"Greater Manchester",
        "value":5,
        "color":"#eea638"
    },
    {
        "code":"córdoba",
        "name":"Córdoba",
        "value":3,
        "color":"#eea638"
    },
    {
        "code":"coimbra",
        "name":"Coimbra",
        "value":4,
        "color":"#eea638"
    },
    {
        "code":"soest",
        "name":"Soest",
        "value":1,
        "color":"#eea638"
    }
]
}
}
```

the result i get is this:
[image]

what i would like to know if there is a way to do a autozoom that would include all the ballons.

Comment: There's no such built-in feature. However, technically, it should be possible to setup a handler for "clickMapObject" which would calculate zoom parameters needed to incorporate all of the bubbles into view, if you're feeling like taking a stab at it.

Comment: hmm not sure how i would do that, but guess ill investigate a bit further

Comment: ok i managed to do what i wanted, but i would like to have it when i load page, so clickMapObject event inst quite right, any other sort of event i can use? i noticed map doesn't have init.

Comment: ok i managed to do what i wanted, thanks for the help

Comment: @Ric can you share your solution, please?

Comment: @Ric can you please share your solution?